# Database: Relation between one attribute to several entity instances

Tags: database, relation

Is there such a thing? I'm not implementing anything, I'm just creating an E-R Diagram from it. Here is a simple example:

```
ENT(Ent_ID, Group_IDs)
GROUP(Group_ID, Att)
```

The attribute `Group_ID` would have an one-to-many relationship with different instances of `GROUP`. (Is the word instance correct here?)

P.s: I know I could create a third entity with Ent_ID and Group_ID as attributes to make the relations if I was implementing it, but I don't know if this has to be specified in the diagram.

Answer (score 0):

The way I understand your example, you have a *one-to-many* relation:

Each `GROUP` instance can have many `ENT` instances related, but every `ENT` instance is related to one *and only one* `GROUP` instance.

Comment: The other way around. It is one ENT to several GROUP. Using the attribute Group_IDs inside of ENT was my approach to the implementation, as if it was holding several GROUP ids.

Comment: @Arthurso So `Group_IDs` holds multiple values for each `Ent_ID`?

Comment: Right. I'm not sure if doing that is correct though. My ultimate goal is to have a single ENT with relationships to several GROUP instances.